# Linux: How to compress approximately 3TB sized folder

Tags: linux, ftp, compression, tar

I need to back up a folder containing more than 2500 sub folders and around 3TB size then ftp it to windows based FTP Server.
As i know tar command is not able to do so.
Thus is it possible to create a script to "tar" each 500 sub folders?
If yes please share your command.
BTW: one way i would do is just using mput in ftp without compression:

```
touch ftp_temp.sh
chmod +x ftp_temp.sh
vim ftp_temp.sh :
'''
#!/bin/bash
HOST='10. 20.30.40'
USER='ftpuser'
PASSWD='ftpuserpasswd'
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd upload
mput 
bye
EOT
'''
```

Comment: Why do you think that tar cannot do what you need? Is it the size you are having a problem with or the number of files? tar should be capable of doing what you need.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very i searched over and over seems size matters. I can see in my nohub.log   that tar : exitrd due to previous error

Comment: Have a read at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405692/what-is-maximum-number-of-files-you-can-store-in-a-tar-archive-under-solaris-11

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern may give you an idea:

```sh
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 500 echo
```

`find` will locate the names of all directories in the current directory, while `xargs` will pass up to 500 of them at a time to another command (in the above example, the `echo` command).

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check it after holiday